# boto3 dict to json to text format in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to create a text file from my boto3 response in a AWS Lambda function which I want to upload to my S3. Here's what I have so far.

```
          import boto3
          import json
          s3 = boto3.client('s3')
          clientVPN = boto3.client('ec2')
          clientVPN = clientVPN.export_client_vpn_client_configuration(ClientVpnEndpointId='arn-of-clientVPN-id', DryRun=False)
              clientVPN_string = json.dumps(clientVPN, indent=2)
              response = s3.put_object(Bucket=myBucket, Body=clientVPN_string, Key='configuration.ovpn')
```

With what I have above, I'm able to write the file into S3. However, the file looks like below:

```
{
  "ClientConfiguration": "client\ndev tun\nproto udp\nremote xxxx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443\nremote-random-hostname\nresolv-retry infinite\nnobind\nremote-cert-tls server\ncipher AES-256-GCM\nverb 3\n<ca>\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxx/2x\ncxxBr\nkw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n\n</ca>\n\n\nreneg-sec 0",
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "40b87d13-edb9-4f3e-85e0-9b9f233518d9",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "x-amzn-requestid": "40b87d13-edb9-4f3e-85e0-9b9f233518d9",
      "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "vary": "accept-encoding",
      "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
      "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
      "date": "Sat, 26 Feb 2022 19:25:22 GMT",
      "server": "AmazonEC2"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}
```

However, the output from AWS CLI gives me a neat txt format which would look as below:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxxx.amazonaws.com 443
remote-random-hostname
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>


reneg-sec 0
```

As we can see in the output, I would like to extract only the "***ClientConfiguration***" and neatly formatted as lines as provided by the AWS CLI output. I've tried several ways to do it like below but unfortunately I'm not having luck.

```
   clientVPN_string = json.dumps(clientVPN, indent=2)
   for key, value in clientVPN_string.items():
     with open('client.ovpn', 'a') as the_file:
       print(value)
```

Is there any way to convert the output am getting with boto3 to the txt format like how AWS CLI provides? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the methods `decode("utf-8")` and `json.loads()` will work for you.

Example:

```
def get_data_from_s3(name):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'bucket_name'
    result = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)
    for o in result.get('Contents'):
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=o.get('Key'))
        contents = data['Body'].read()
        client_vpn_body = contents.decode("utf-8")
        client_vpn_json = json.loads(client_vpn_body)
        print(client_vpn_json['ClientConfiguration'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not reading anything from S3 though. I want to write to s3 the output of export_client_vpn_client_configuration in the text format.